# What are the two protocols used by SQL Server Windows authentication?

Tags: sql-server

I was asked this question in an interview, and I have no idea what the answer is.

I know we have Windows authentication mode and SQL Server authentication. But the interviewer said that we have two protocols that Windows verify when using Windows authentication.

I just can't find anything on the Internet about this.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

They were probably looking for an answer that discuss the "Kerberos" and "NTLM" Windows authentication protocol/schemes.

Once you know what to search for, there are lots of articles online about how these schemes relate to SQL Server:

- [Questions About Kerberos and SQL Server That You Were Too Shy to Ask](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/database-administration/questions-about-kerberos-and-sql-server-that-you-were-too-shy-to-ask/)
- [Understanding Kerberos and NTLM authentication in SQL Server Connections](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sql_protocols/2006/12/02/understanding-kerberos-and-ntlm-authentication-in-sql-server-connections/)

  > In the **NTLM protocol**, the client sends the user name to the server; the server generates and sends a challenge to the client; the client encrypts that challenge using the user’s password; and the client sends a response to the server.

  ...and

  > Kerberos authentication (**protocol**) provides a mechanism for mutual authentication between a client and a server on an open network.

  <sup>*Comment: **emphasis/meaning** added*</sup>
- [How to make sure that you are using Kerberos authentication when you create a remote connection to an instance of SQL Server 2005](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/909801/how-to-make-sure-that-you-are-using-kerberos-authentication-when-you-c)